# What is the maven dependency for cucumber-jvm before hook?

Tags: junit, cucumber-jvm

I am trying to create a before hook for my cucumber-jvm tests. I have added the `@before` annotation on my method. I have also imported `cucumber.annotation.Before` in that file. However, the import is not resolved. I cannot figure out what is the maven dependency for this import. This is what I have in my pom file:

```
<properties>
    <cucumber.version>1.2.2</cucumber.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Comment: Found the answer. The import is `cucumber.api.java.Before`. It looks like in some previos version the import was `cucumber.annotation.Before`.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer. The import is `cucumber.api.java.Before`. It looks like in some previous version the import was `cucumber.annotation.Before`.